# Regex: Capture a word between two words

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say these are my inputs:

> type    Database    xyz{ abc }
>
> type    Database    { abc }

I want to capture just this in both the cases

> Database

The pattern is:

"type" + any number of spaces + what i want + any number of spaces + any characters

I've this so far but I'm not sure how to match any character in look ahead.
`(?<=type)\s+(.*)(?=)`

Comment: Is Database a "word" maybe? What kind of character can be in there? Why are you trying to match anything after Database if it can be anything and you're not really interested?

Comment: yes i don't need to match anything after it. you're right. i was complicating it. i only need to match the first word that comes after "type"

Comment: (?<=\btype\s)(\w+) << this is working. can you confirm if tis correct?

Comment: Any number of spaces isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you don't need a lookbehind, because just matching and capturing the second word should work:

```
String input = "type Database xyz{ abc }";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("type\\s+(.*?)\\s+.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

That finds the word and prints

```
Type: Database
```

Comment: Isn't `find` a bit tricky if you can have anything after the "word"? Maybe anchor it to the start of each line or something similar?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Are you suggesting that the pattern can be found multiple times in the input? I'm assuming that could be the case and the OP wants to pull all occurrences. Otherwise, the OP can just use `input.split("\\s+")[1]`. But they'd know better.

Comment: i may have misread your answer but its not finding any matches: https://regexr.com/4v3o6

Comment: You have to remove one of the double backward slashes probably. Twice.

Comment: @90abyss I think Maarten is right. When I unescape the backslash, I see it matches types in group 1. Not quite sure how that system works.